# in swift source Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift

```
func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvents event:UIEvent) {  
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        player.position.x = location.x
    }
}
```

it gives me this following error

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: Which line exactly you are getting this error?

But I can see you are calling `locationInNode` from `touch`, which is typed as a `AnyObject`. If `locationInNode` is not defined within `AnyObject` you will have an error. You must cast to your known type to be able to call it

Comment: i'm not really sure, this was my very first project using swift, it's in the `for touch: AnyObject in touches {` line. so how exactly can i define the `locationInNode` within the `AnyObject` ?

Comment: I believe you shouldn't, `AnyObject` is a protocol to which all classes must conform. 

Why are you using `AnyObject` here? Can't you use a less generic protocol or even a Class type?

Comment: i did changed it to a Class type before, but it gives me another error on the same line says something about the `NSSet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like Swift 2 code. The current signature is

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        player.position.x = location.x
    }
}
```

And if we are talking about Swift 2 then cast `NSSet` to native `Set` and it's certainly `withEvent` (singular)

```
func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event:UIEvent) {  
    for touch in touches as Set<UITouch> {
```